# Where I can find @Inject jar

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm following the MVC unit test instructions from [this site](http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2010/03/integration-testing-of-springs-mvc-annotation-mapppings-for-controllers/),
but I cannot find the jar for the `@Inject` annotation.  Does anybody know where the jar is?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Via Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or from the Project Home Page: http://code.google.com/p/atinject/

Also, [this MvnRepository.com page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject/1) provides the necessary configurations for other build tools like Ivy, Gradle etc.

Answer (score 10):

Using `javaee-api` instead of `javax.inject` I ran into a bunch of issues.

After some digging I found out that you need to add it with scope provided or otherwise it will add a Listener (`com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener`) at runtime.

Another issue is that apparently the implementation to inject is different. Fields annotated with `@inject` remained null. By replacing the official sun jar with the `javax.inject`, this no longer happened.

Note that i'm not an expert, I might be running into side-effects, but figuring this out took me such a long time, that I felt I had to share my findings so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Sun's official:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Cheers!

Comment: That looks like a couple dozen packages bundled together.  I would advise against using this unless you both need all of them and know that none of them are being pulled into your project individually.  I think that artifact would have been better had it simply listed dependencies on the others, rather than completely repacking them into one.

Answer (score 2):

[Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4131469/507761) on [`javax.inject:javax.inject`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject) is great, but note also that the modern version of this library is [`jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.inject/jakarta.inject-api) ([source code](https://github.com/jakartaee/inject)).  The artifact was renamed to that starting with `1.0` (different from `1`), but the classes were kept in the `javax.inject` package for backwards compatibility.  Starting with `2.0.0`, the classes are now in the `jakarta.inject` package.

It's possible to pull in both the old v1 artifact and v2.0.0+ of the new artifact if you need to support both packages, which is a fairly common case in large projects with a mix of older and newer dependencies.  Maven config:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Note also that there are alternative providers of these classes.  Some of the ones most likely to run into:

- `javax:javaee-api`, as mentioned in [Darko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315850/507761)
- `javax.inject:inject`
- `javax.inject:inject-api`
- `javax.inject:jsr330-api`, and *many* other artifacts with `jsr330` in the name
- `org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject`

I recommend [using `maven-enforcer-plugin` to ban](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) these dependencies.  When it detects them and fails, you can add [dependency exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions) to prevent them from being pulled in transitively.  Just make sure to have an explicit dependency on the official version replacing it; otherwise, you may hit runtime issues.

There are also shaded versions bundled into other libraries that move the classes into an entirely different package; there's nothing you can do about that (at least not simply), but it should be fine since they won't conflict.

---

Finally, note that while modern versions of [the Guice injection framework](https://github.com/google/guice) support one or both of the official implementations (Jakarta support was added in Guice 6.0 and 7.0), support was somewhat lacking in older versions.  If you use an older version of Guice (prior to 4.2 in my experience), you might need to use their version: `com.google.inject.Inject` from [`com.google.inject:guice`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice).