# spring @inject not working in Controller

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am using context:component-scan, still the dependencies are not getting injected.

Here is my setup. ConnectionHelper property is not getting injected in the LoginController class.

WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>vd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>



<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>vd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

</beans>
```

WEB-INF/vd-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Configures Handler Interceptors -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.example.interceptors.SslInterceptor" />
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/login" />
        <bean class="com.example.interceptors.SslInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/WEB-INF/views/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

com.example.controllers.LoginController.java

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Inject
private ConnectionHelper connectionHelper;    //this is null after loading

}
```

com.example.connection.ConnectionHelper.java

```
@Component
public class ConnectionHelper {

}
```

Please tell me what's wrong here...after hours of troubleshooting i can't determine the problem.

**Update**

I changed my configuration and moved everything to vd-servlet.xml.

Quite miraculously I have found that `@Autowired` works (Injects Dependencies) with this configuration but `@Inject` does not.

And `<mvc:annotation-driven />` is still required even if you use   `<context:component-scan />`, otherwise @RequestMapping is not detected.

vd-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.example.interceptors.SslInterceptor" />
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/login" />
        <bean class="com.example.interceptors.SslInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/WEB-INF/views/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: This is a great question with all the right details included. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Alex, just that the file where you are missing `<context:component-scan/>` or `<context:annotation-config/>` is not applicationContext.xml file but `vd-servlet.xml` file.

Either `<context:annnotation-config/>` or `<context:component-scan/>` will register a [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) responsible for handling @Autowired, @Resource, @Inject annotations

Comment: Like @Alex says Sumit, you do required mvc:annotation-driven. Component scan simply finds all the beans in the package, but it is annotation-driven that iterates over the beans, detects their @RequestMapping annotation and creates the mapping. @Inject should have worked just like @Autowired - you mentioned that @Autowired works for you. Can you confirm that you have the jar containing `javax.inject.Inject` in your classpath

Comment: javaee-web-api-6.0.jar, which contains javax.inject.Inject is on my compilation classpath, but I removed it from deployment because tomcat complains if i put it in runtime classpath `validateJarFile(webclient\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-web-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class` as it has its own copy of servlet apis, i think tomcat does not support @Inject then. Is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you try this jar instead - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131190/where-i-can-find-inject-jar , yes having the entire web-api jar would probably conflict with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your applicationContext.xml is missing:

`<context:annotation-config>`

this registers Springs post processors for annotation based configuration.

Comment: `component-scan` does the same thing, however there is a `annotation-config/component-scan` missing in `vd-servlet.xml`, adding that should fix the issue.

Comment: But ironically if i skip <context:annotation-config> and just use component:scan, then @RequestMapping are not detected.

Comment: You need `<mvc:annotation-driven>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add getters and setters to the `LoginController`. Another option is to make `connectionHelper` a `protected` variable. This is how Spring "sees" the property to be injected.

In `LoginController`:

```
@Inject
private ConnectionHelper connectionHelper;

public ConnectionHelper getConnectionHelper() {
    return connectionHelper;
}

public void setConnectionHelper(ConnectionHelper connectionHelper) {
    this.connectionHelper = connectionHelper;
}
```

Comment: Spring will inject private variables just fine without a getter and setter.